# RegEx matching problem with array.indexOf() in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't get IndexOf to match correctly in GAS

I've tested out my regular expression here:
https://regex101.com/r/0cK6xQ/1

As soon as there is a space inside the string, indexOf() will not match.
I even tried setting the regex as `let contactRegExp = /(contact 1 Type)/i ;` , which should be a direct match for the 2nd element in the sample array and it bombs out.

```
function setContactTypes(){  

 //Find all contact Type columns
 let contactRegExp = /(contact [\d]* Type)/i ;

 var headerIndexList = ['dummy1','contact 1 Type','dummy2','contact 2 Type'];

 var hitArray = [];
 var i = -1;
 while ((i = headerIndexList.indexOf(contactRegExp,(i+1))) != -1){
     hitArray.push(i);
  }
}
```

hitArray should return [1,3]

I'm thinking it has something to do with an Array vs a string, but for the life of me can't figure it out.

Comment: You could use String.prototype.search() to search for patern into the strings of your array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Array.prototype.indexOf()` cannot use the regex. So in your situation, in order to achieve your goal, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function setContactTypes(){  
 let contactRegExp = /(contact [\d]* Type)/i ;
 var headerIndexList = ['dummy1','contact 1 Type','dummy2','contact 2 Type'];
 var hitArray = headerIndexList.reduce((ar, e, i) => {
   if (contactRegExp.test(e)) ar.push(i);
   return ar;
  }, []);
  console.log(hitArray) // When your "headerIndexList" is used, [1, 3] is returned.
}
```

#### Testing:

```js
let contactRegExp = /(contact [\d]* Type)/i ;
var headerIndexList = ['dummy1','contact 1 Type','dummy2','contact 2 Type'];
var hitArray = headerIndexList.reduce((ar, e, i) => {
  if (contactRegExp.test(e)) ar.push(i);
  return ar;
}, []);
console.log(hitArray)
```

#### References:

- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

### Added:

For example, the following script is useful for your situation?

```js
let contactRegExp = /(contact [\d]* Type)/i;
var headerIndexList = ['dummy1', 'contact 1 Type', 'dummy2', 'contact 2 Type'];
var hitArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < headerIndexList.length; i++) {
  if (contactRegExp.test(headerIndexList[i])) {
    hitArray.push(i);
  }
}
console.log(hitArray)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. This is close. Would prefer to use the `i` value as input for another set of instructions right away. However I can use the output array and loop through it with a few extra steps.  Still racking my brain on how the reduce function works.

Comment: @ThePirate Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `Would prefer to use the i value as input for another set of instructions right away.`. I thought that you wanted to retrieve `[1, 3]` from `headerIndexList` and `contactRegExp`. Is my understanding correct? Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: 大丈夫です. Your English is better than my Japanese.
`while ((i = headerIndexList.indexOf(contactRegExp,(i+1))) != -1){
    // callotherFunction(i);
   //  callmoreFunction(i, 'string');
  }`

You have been a big help.. Thank you.

Comment: @ThePirate Thank you for replying. Now I added one more sample script using the for loop. Is that useful for your situation? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: いい頭. Perfect. ありがとうございました. Your added script works perfect.